# English equivalent to Russian "Ты обалдел/офигел/etc.?"

Tags: phrase-requests, russian

Basically, *"обалдеть/офигеть/охренеть"* and their vulgar counterparts in Russian are informal and quite expressive words of shock and surprise.

> – Our country has won 50 medals total at the Olympics.
>   – *Обалдеть!* (**No way!/Holy cow!**/etc.)

---

Another way of usage is to address a person whose words or actions don't meet with your approval and are mostly offensive.

> – Mom, I've decided to quit university for a career of a stripper.
>   – *Ты обалдела, что ли?*

In this case the translation could be "**Have you gone mad?**" or such, though it would be more precise for expressions like "*сойти с ума/сдуреть/слететь с катушек*/etc."

What I can't seem to find is a more aggressive and menacing phrase. You usually use it instantly when someone unexpectedly does or says something unacceptable to you.

> – [Grabs her buttock]
>   – *Офигел?* Get your hands off!

In such situations the word is identical to "*обнаглеть/оборзеть*" which literally means "**to grow impudent**". You can put it in affirmative sentences as well:

> – I've spent all the money you gave me for the month, again.
>   – Ну ты уж совсем *офигел*, друг мой. (roughly "**This is too much/You've gone too far**, my boy.")

This question really baffles me since I can't think of any "catch phrase" in English with the similar meaning despite it being quite a commonplace in Russian. If there aren't at all, I wonder what a native speaker would say in these sort of situations (and hope I've made it clear enough as to the meaning).

Comment: Which phrase are you looking for? Something like, **"What the f--- ?!"**

Comment: @Hank Perhaps I should've been more specific. The one that I'm looking for is in the title. "**What the f---**" is rather vague, I need something you could apply directly to a person. It's like asking if they've lost their good manners or common sense, but in a really quick and informal way.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPNIOAI5eHM

Comment: Perhaps, **"Are you sh--ting me?!"** (more vulgar and emphatic version of "Are you kidding me?")

Comment: Let me leave something of a backstory here. As I was making English subtitles for a Russian video, this phrase came along and I still have no idea how to translate it. I let it be "Are you nuts?" which in my case is acceptable. But generally it needs to answer sassiness rather than insanity.

Comment: @Skooba I was considering that too. If there aren't any closer ones I guess that's it.

Comment: @fixer1234 This one's more about shock and surprise, like in my first example.

Comment: _"Unbelievable!"_ could work in all four scenarios.

Comment: "Are you (f---ing) kidding me?" shows both shock and dismay. It is stronger with the optional expletive.

Comment: @DFlight if you have one specific phrase in mind, as you said in the earlier comment, it would help to share that phrase. You gave 4 examples in the question, but then you said you were interested in one specific use for the video you were translating. You could provide the link to the video as well by the way, to give a better context to all Russian speakers reading this question. As mentioned before by other users, there are too many different uses and flavours of the expression to cover them all with just one phrase.

Comment: @vovick Seems I'm confusing everyone including myself right now. The first example is actually irrelevant in this question and was meant to sort it out for Russian speakers, I guess? (to separate two meanings) As for the rest, I can imagine one phrase (which is in the title) being used for the three different scenarios and still have almost the same meaning. To find out if there was an equivalent to that was my purpose exactly. So far it looks like the whole point of the expression is unfamiliar to English speakers (or it may be I'm just bad at explanations).

Comment: @vovick And I mean, it's totally fine to have such a result. It must be obvious to me at this point that the language reflects people's mentality, and the slightest details in the way people react to things can differ between different peoples.

Comment: Translation is weird (as you well know). Literal word for word usually sounds terrible in the target language. Mostly the right sentiment and register is usually possible, but might miss some important cultural references or even important feelings, and a loose idea can just make bilingual speakers shake their heads in disbelief. I don't understand Russian, but everything you've said so far makes 'WTF' sound just right. Actually, all the current answers fit also. I offer another 'crazy': 1) That's crazy 2) Are you crazy? 3) Are you crazy? 4) You're crazy.

Comment: @DFlight "the language reflects people's mentality" - I'm not a linguist or psychologist, but I think that in the scenarios that you've described everyone simply has a pre-made generic response to express their feelings. Ever and anon we happen to be amazed by some news or hurt and perplexed by other people's lack of insight and horrible manners, so eventually everyone just develops a token verbal retort to instantly use in such situations. Whether those things are expressed with one particular phrase or different ones seems tangential as the response is mostly a knee-jerk reaction. (IMHO!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What the hell is wrong with you!?"

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Another one that came to my mind is "What the hell do you think you're doing?". What I like about both of them is being able to change the intensifier e.g. _on earth, the hell, the heck_ etc., bringing variation and your personal touch.
I accept this, though will be open for other variants.

Answer (score 1):

> – We won 50 medals [at the Olympics].
> – No f___ing way!
>
> – Mom, I've decided to quit university to work as a stripper.
> – F___ that!
>
> – [Grabs her buttock]
> – F___ off!
>
> – I've spent all the money you gave me for the month, again.
> – F__ that!

It's vulgar, expressive, aggressive, shocked -- and natural (in the U.S. -- not sure about British English).  I would never say it, but it sounds like this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is worthy of note though that the phrase in question has several degrees of rudeness, depending on which word is used in the same construction. The mildest variations, despite being informal, are not even considered vulgar.
But as far as I know, there are quite a few euphemisms for the F word expressions in English, so making them more polite is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the expressions discussed in the question is that they are time and place sensitive. What is current and common today may not be so in twenty years, nor twenty years past.

> goddamn!

This expletive is common and old in  English. Stories have it that English people were once known as "goddamns" in some parts of the world, as "goddamn" seemed to be the most common thing said said by Englishmen.[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_goddams)
"Goddamn" is very versatile.

> Goddamn it, what do you mean you're pregnant?
>
> Your incompetence is known in every corner of the goddamn world!

There is really no end as to how the term can be used.

> You've got one goddamn minute to get out of here.
>   How did you do on the goddamn test?
>   Goddamn, you going to just sit there all day?

In literature, "fu##king" seems to have replaced "goddamn", but, I'm not sure how versatile it is. [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=goddamn%2Cfucking&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgoddamn%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfucking%3B%2Cc0)

My vote will go to "goddamn" for durability and versatility.